# Why is snap bone to cursor not working in pose mode?

Tags: bones

Question is pretty self explained. It's snapping to wierd places when there is a clamp to constraint...

The bones original pos:

[image]

where it is now:

[image]

Comment: Someone help please!

Comment: A picture would help to explain IHMO.  Show your constraint, desired goal and failed result if possible.  Screen captures can be edited and cropped and annotated  in the free GIMP (open source) or less directly in Blender as a texture. Sometimes a whole screen capture is inferior because the image is scaled so that text is NOT readable in the  settings of Blender.

Comment: Please keep your useful comments and delete the others.  Your pictures are difficult to read because they are so large and thus are scaled down.  Consider capturing only .5 or .25 of screen, not whole screen where some of image does not convey information.  Consider Path Constraint and Conform Constraint.  My suggested change of title and question .... How can I work effectively with the Conform Constraint?  Are there better alternatives?  Here is my larger Goal of animating moving track for (something)???  Do not reveal your trade secrets of course.

Answer (score 4):

[Clamp To] Constraint  wins over manual placement such as [Snap To].

- An active [clamp to] constraint of influence 1, with a disconnected bone, will dominate any manual position for final placment.  This is useful, designed, and meets the expectation of the Blender user who is informed.  Snap to is manual placement.  Standard specification and behavior.
- Verify your bone is NOT connected to parent in bone edit mode.  Then the bone should follow the curve.

[image]

- You may change your curve to be pass through any location including the cursor location.  Suit to your needs.
- Be aware the constraints can be turned off and on with the eye option, and their influence can be set from 0 to 1 on the constraint panel.  Both of these options can use animation keyframes. So if you reduce the influence to zero with keyframes the bone will be off the curve for those keyframes.  Thus you can have a bone follow the curve or be off the curve as suits your animation.

[image]

- If a constraint is used to control placement it dominates over manual placement.  That is the designed behavior.

Comment: so how can i make it stay where it is after adding a clamp to? it was right on top of the curve already i dont see why it moved

Comment: I added pictures

Comment: If you are going to use a constraint and not rewrite it at the software level  you must cooperate with its behavior.  The constraint may not have every feature you want.  Options Auto XYZ.  If you choose X option for example then a manual movement of X will move the bone around the curve.  The constraint determines final placement.  After  constraint is placed ... move the bone in the X direction and constraint will eventually place it on the curve in your desired location.  You can observe and work with that behavior.  Experiment.  Move the bone manually to cooperate with the constraint.

Comment: But precise placement?

Comment: Be Clear.  Your question is unclear.  Please demonstrate more effort and precision in your question.  Please use a full sentence.  If I guess what you meant .. I can make random comments such as ... the curve specified is the precise placement.  Use multiple constraints. You may get the result you want with lots of work.  Because you have not stated your larger goal this discussion is difficult.  Also please state whether or not we are making positive progress.  If we are not making progress we should stop. We should consider chat here if the site suggests it. Are we making any progress?

Comment: How can I move my bone precisely? Like my bone goes right over the cursor yet it won't snap to it

Comment: Make your curve or keyframe precise.  Animate Influence.   The curve start point or endpoint can be coincident with some special location.   Specify  X option in constraint. Animate the X position of bone to stop when you visually see its correct location. Insert <<<<keyframe>>.  Cease using the Snap To terminology if it is confusing with the user action Snap To.  Are we making positive progress ? Yes or No?

Comment: So just use judgement. Isn't that a little inaccurate?

Comment: I'm getting closer to what I need. Yes we are making progress.

Comment: Designate your 100% accurate point in 3D space.  Put a Bezier curve endpoint at the exact location.  If this style of visual programming is not acceptable ... use a Blender Python driver with more work.  When you provide an example, simplified or not, of what you are trying to achieve and state how accurate you must be then others can help.  Machine part for Virgin Galactic requires high accuracy unless explosions are acceptable.  Background tracks moving quickly and distantly requires less accuracy.  Chat or break soon.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23841/discussion-between-aidan-pallian-and-atomicbezierslinger).

Comment: Did you delete your messages? are you still here?